# How to style google maps with Android SDK (map structure)

Tags: java, json, maps

Can somebody explain me how to integrate the following example in to your project files.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling

I want to customise the maps, I don't understand how they reference/file structure works with it. I want to add it in a existing project.

Comment: there are many tutorials for doing it. this site is not for helping them.

Comment: According to the docs you linked, copy `style_json.json` to `/res/raw/` and make your maps activity implement `onMapReadyCallback` then use `map.setMapStyle()` inside the callback. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @PrashanthChandra I've posted the code in another question, was too long for a comment.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657304/google-maps-style-is-not-applying-on-all-maps-in-java-document-android-studio

Hope you can check it out.